# How to pass image file to the HTML file selector automatically thru script without the need of the user to manually select it thru chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, file, select

I have a forum to fill in which I am passing the information in the fields thru a JSON file. Fields like name, description, date, etc. The problem that I am facing is how can I pass the image file in the HTML select element without manually selecting it thru the mouse. I just want to pass the source of the file thru a JSON file and the script automatically loads it and uploads it. There are thousands of data to be filled and images to be attached, which is why I want a script to run and upload all the data into the forum plus images automatically.

```
function pasteData() {
  let name = document.querySelector("#name");
  let description = document.querySelector("#description");
  let media = document.querySelector("#media");
  name.value = json.name;
  description.value = json.description; 
}
```

Here is the code so far for the name and description fields. I do not know how to tackle the image part.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to be possible.  Imagine a world where any website you visit can silently upload any file from your file system without having to ask you...

Comment: No, that's simply impossible without user input.

Comment: @David but we are passing the information thru chrome extension knowingly.

Comment: @AliIftikhar You never mentioned anything about a Chrome Extension in your question. That's a very important detail.

Comment: @Dai Sorry, I just mentioned it.